# Filling whitespaces in JAVA with characters

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that takes a string, goes through it character by character, and replaces the whitespace with another character, 'Z' in this case. I wrote the following code. It seems like the program goes into an infinite `for` loop. Why is that happening?

Expected output is: Thisziszthezday

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder("This is the day");
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
            if (word.charAt(j) == ' ') {
                word.insert(j, 'z');
            }
        }

        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not replacing the whitespace, but instead you are inserting `'z'` before the whitespace so it's an infinite loop as once `word.charAt(j) == ' '` is true, it will continue to be true.

Comment: Use `StringBuilder.setCharAt(int index, char ch)` instead of `insert()`, since insert makes the length of your stringbuilder increase by 1 and the for-loop will never end.

Comment: Oh i get what you're saying. So i how do i replace with the whitespace instead of inserting the z?

Comment: @radoh Is correct, note it is called like `word.setCharAt(j, 'z')`, not `StringBuilder.setCharAt(j, 'z')`.

Comment: @EliSadoff Thanks, that fixed the problem :)